# ajax sending IList to controller

Tags: c#, jquery, ajax

I can't seem to figure out how to send data to a controller that has an IList. In my example, my C# looks like:

```
    public ICollection<KeyValuePair<int, SaveStatus>> StatusUpload(IList<StatusModel> status, int id)
    {
        var statusList = new List<KeyValuePair<int, SaveStatus>>();
        var mainStuff = UnitOfWork.MainRespository.GetAll();
        var subStuff= UnitOfWork.SubRepository.GetAll();
        for (var i = 0; i < addresses.Count; i++)... etc...
```

What I am sending to the controller is:

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: '/MainController/StatusUpload',
    data: { status: status }
}).done(function(results){
    console.log(results);
})
```

and status consists of this object:

```
var status = [];
var innerAddresses = {
        First: first,
        Second: second,
        Third: third,
}
status.push(innerStatus);
```

with the result of status looking like:

```
0: { First: 1, Second: second, Third: 2},
1: { First: 2, Second: second, Third: 3},
2: { First: 3, Second: second, Third: 4}
```

Comment: What is being passed to your controller method from your AJAX call when you run the project? Also, do have appropriate routes set up for you methods?

Comment: yes the routes are correct, im passing an object that has objects with defined values that are part of a view model

Comment: Also, why are you using `List<KeyValuePair<>>` instead of `Dictionary<>`?

Comment: an enum is needed to save, that is what the List <KeyValuePair> is for

Comment: What is the problem ? Is model binding not working for your action method parameters ?  also you do not need `Controller` suffix when making the call.

Comment: the way we use it is we make a call to the controller/then the method

Comment: @Keith, allow me to rephrase - are your `status` and `id` parameters null when you hit that controller method?

Comment: no i cant even get to the controller is the problem, i havent had to work with a controller like this so i'm confused on how to send data to this controller

Comment: if i'm sending the data incorrectly, that is what my question is pertaining to then. how do i send data to this controller correctly

Comment: The problem is the route, most likely. You should not be hitting `/MainController/StatusUpload` but rather `/Main/StatusUpload`

Comment: i tried with main as well, that doesnt seem to be the problem

Comment: Open your browser devtools->console/network and you will see some useful information there.

Comment: In your action method add `[HttpPost]`

Comment: ahh i see an issue, this is in the BLL, not in the controller, do I need to build a controller first and then make a call to this?

Comment: well, if you call an action method that doesn't exists, chances are it would fail.